# How to load a ton of images fast?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, lazy-loading

my website currently hosts a lot of product photos, over 1k. We have the next/previous page system but i want to make them load in one go. Its like 200 products with 20 sub-products each loading when viewing the site and the images spin using carouFredSel. Lazy loading completly crashes the site/script. Haven't tried Scroll Pagination yet but i think it will explode too. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: To get any useful answers, you're going to have to better explain what you're suggesting, and give examples of what you've tried, and what didn't work.

Comment: You should implement a combination of AJAX and css stripes.

Comment: Do you think your users will appreciate downloading all of your images up front, even though they may not end up viewing them?  A lot of people pay by the KB for their internet.

Comment: more bandwidth? well the host says unlimited. css stripes havent use them , i see what i can do. currently the images are in a database and are beeing called with codeigniter various parameters , like"<img src='".$pImage."' />";

Comment: not your host, me the user who is being forced to download 1k of images. and there is no such thing as 'unlimited'

Comment: what i tried : http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/14/ also, http://luis-almeida.github.com/unveil. nothing works, the site takes too long to load and the actuall script crashes. without scripts it takes ~30sec to load, thats ages !

Comment: accept the limitations of transferring data over the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your site traffic you would be using a  lot of bandwidth to load all these photos (which i am sure you are aware of) and are you sure your customers really want to have all your products blasted in there face in one go?

you should make a list of the two hundred catagories which loads dynamically. you would make a an ajax call to a php script(or whever ever language you are coding in)
 which selects the next 20 product catagories from your db every time the user scrolls down x% of the screen(depending on your layout). then below each catagory you could put a hidden div which opens out when the user click on the catagory , when the open div event is fired you can also start making ajax requests to get images for the sub catagories, load them into your carosel or wherever.

loading 1000 images  of every product that you have into one page seems insane and really heavy! I understand your need but i think you need to consider how you implement this one

Comment: to be clear the site is this one : http://14u-fashion.com/shop/cat/65 , the experimental version of the same site is without the next/previous. You see the images themselfs are not a lot , its the sub-ones that are hundreads (the auto-spinning thing) maybe i should load only the first one and put the others on the product press page?

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called galleria that would probably work well for you. You would just have to load your photos to a site like flickr to add as many as you are.

http://galleria.io/

Comment: i use galleria and im aware of its uses , i prefer the images to be on my site though.

Comment: At one time I used a php program that loaded images from a directory, im just trying to remember what it was called.